# RIOSendEx get error 10022 but connect + RIOSend works well

Tags: windows

I'm learning Windows Registered I/O, I found a sample project from the website "https://github.com/zeliard/RIOEchoServer", It does well on my computer.

However, if I change this code from the listening server side to the actively sending client side, I find that `connect` + `RIOSend` works fine, but `RIOSendEx` will definitely give an error code of `10022`!

```
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <MSWsock.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    static const wchar_t SERVER[] = L"127.0.0.1";
    static const unsigned short PORTNUM = 54321;
    static const DWORD RIO_PENDING_RECVS = 1;
    static const DWORD RIO_PENDING_SENDS = 1;
    static const DWORD RECV_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
    static const DWORD SEND_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
    static const DWORD ADDR_BUFFER_SIZE = 64;
    static const DWORD RIO_MAX_RESULTS = 1;

    WSADATA wsadata;
    if (0 != ::WSAStartup(0x202, &wsadata))
    {
        printf_s("WSAStartup Error: %d\n", GetLastError());
        exit(0);
    }

    /// RIO socket
    SOCKET socket = WSASocket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP, NULL, 0, WSA_FLAG_REGISTERED_IO);
    if (socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf_s("WSASocket Error: %d\n", GetLastError());
        exit(0);
    }

    /// RIO function table
    GUID functionTableId = WSAID_MULTIPLE_RIO;
    DWORD dwBytes = 0;
    RIO_EXTENSION_FUNCTION_TABLE rio;
    if (NULL != WSAIoctl(socket, SIO_GET_MULTIPLE_EXTENSION_FUNCTION_POINTER, &functionTableId, sizeof(GUID), (void**)&rio, sizeof(rio), &dwBytes, NULL, NULL))
    {
        printf_s("WSAIoctl Error: %d\n", GetLastError());
        exit(0);
    }

    /// rio's completion manner: iocp
    HANDLE hIOCP = ::CreateIoCompletionPort(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, 0, 0, 0);
    if (NULL == hIOCP)
    {
        printf_s("CreateIoCompletionPort Error: %d\n", GetLastError());
        exit(0);
    }


    OVERLAPPED overlapped;
    RIO_NOTIFICATION_COMPLETION completionType;
    completionType.Type = RIO_IOCP_COMPLETION;
    completionType.Iocp.IocpHandle = hIOCP;
    completionType.Iocp.CompletionKey = NULL;
    completionType.Iocp.Overlapped = &overlapped;

    /// creating RIO CQ, which is bigger than (or equal to) RQ size
    RIO_CQ completionQueue = rio.RIOCreateCompletionQueue(RIO_PENDING_RECVS + RIO_PENDING_SENDS, &completionType);
    if (completionQueue == RIO_INVALID_CQ)
    {
        printf_s("RIOCreateCompletionQueue Error: %d\n", GetLastError());
        exit(0);
    }

    /// creating RIO RQ
    /// SEND and RECV within one CQ (you can do with two CQs, seperately)
    RIO_RQ requestQueue = rio.RIOCreateRequestQueue(socket, RIO_PENDING_RECVS, 1, RIO_PENDING_SENDS, 1, completionQueue, completionQueue, NULL);
    if (requestQueue == RIO_INVALID_RQ)
    {
        printf_s("RIOCreateRequestQueue Error: %d\n", GetLastError());
        exit(0);
    }


    /// registering RIO buffers for SEND
    char sendBuffer[SEND_BUFFER_SIZE];
    RIO_BUFFERID sendRioBufferId = rio.RIORegisterBuffer(sendBuffer, static_cast<DWORD>(sizeof(sendBuffer)));
    if (sendRioBufferId == RIO_INVALID_BUFFERID)
    {
        printf_s("RIORegisterBuffer Error: %d\n", GetLastError());
        exit(0);
    }
    RIO_BUF sendRioBuffer;
    sendRioBuffer.BufferId = sendRioBufferId;
    sendRioBuffer.Offset = 0;
    sendRioBuffer.Length = SEND_BUFFER_SIZE;


    /// registering RIO buffers for ADDR
    char addrBuffer[ADDR_BUFFER_SIZE];
    RIO_BUFFERID addrRioBufferId = rio.RIORegisterBuffer(addrBuffer, static_cast<DWORD>(sizeof(addrBuffer)));
    if (addrRioBufferId == RIO_INVALID_BUFFERID)
    {
        printf_s("RIORegisterBuffer Error: %d\n", GetLastError());
        exit(0);
    }
    RIO_BUF addrRioBuffer;
    addrRioBuffer.BufferId = addrRioBufferId;
    addrRioBuffer.Offset = 0;
    addrRioBuffer.Length = ADDR_BUFFER_SIZE;


    /// registering RIO buffers for RECV and then, post pre-RECV
    char recvBuffer[RECV_BUFFER_SIZE];
    RIO_BUFFERID recvRioBufferId = rio.RIORegisterBuffer(recvBuffer, static_cast<DWORD>(sizeof(recvBuffer)));
    if (recvRioBufferId == RIO_INVALID_BUFFERID)
    {
        printf_s("RIORegisterBuffer Error: %d\n", GetLastError());
        exit(0);
    }
    RIO_BUF recvRioBuffer;
    recvRioBuffer.BufferId = recvRioBufferId;
    recvRioBuffer.Offset = 0;
    recvRioBuffer.Length = RECV_BUFFER_SIZE;

    /// posting pre RECVs
    if (!rio.RIOReceiveEx(requestQueue, &recvRioBuffer, 1, NULL, &addrRioBuffer, NULL, 0, 0, &recvRioBuffer))
    {
        printf_s("RIOReceive Error: %d\n", GetLastError());
        exit(0);
    }


    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // active send code begin ...
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    sendRioBuffer.Length = 5;
    memcpy_s(sendBuffer, RECV_BUFFER_SIZE, "hello", sendRioBuffer.Length);

    sockaddr_in * address = reinterpret_cast<sockaddr_in *>(addrBuffer);
    memset(address, 0x0, ADDR_BUFFER_SIZE);
    address->sin_family = AF_INET;
    address->sin_port = htons(PORTNUM);
    if (::InetPton(AF_INET, SERVER, &address->sin_addr) <= 0)
    {
        printf_s("inet_pton Error: %d\n", GetLastError());
        exit(0);
    }

#if 0 // connect + RIOSend is OK

    if (SOCKET_ERROR == ::connect(socket, reinterpret_cast<struct sockaddr *>(address), sizeof(*address)))
    {
        printf_s("Connect Error: %d\n", GetLastError());
        exit(0);
    }

    if (!rio.RIOSend(requestQueue, &sendRioBuffer, 1, 0, &sendRioBuffer))
    {
        printf_s("RIOSend Error: %d\n", GetLastError());
        exit(0);
    }

#else // RIOSendEx not work

    if (!rio.RIOSendEx(requestQueue, &sendRioBuffer, 1, NULL, &addrRioBuffer, NULL, NULL, 0, &sendRioBuffer))
    {
        printf_s("RIOSendEx Error: %d\n", GetLastError());
        exit(0);
    }

#endif // 0

    INT notifyResult = rio.RIONotify(completionQueue);
    if (notifyResult != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf_s("RIONotify Error: %d\n", GetLastError());
        exit(0);
    }

    DWORD numberOfBytes = 0;
    ULONG_PTR completionKey = 0;
    OVERLAPPED* pOverlapped = 0;
    RIORESULT results[RIO_MAX_RESULTS];
    if (!::GetQueuedCompletionStatus(hIOCP, &numberOfBytes, &completionKey, &pOverlapped, INFINITE))
    {
        printf_s("GetQueuedCompletionStatus Error: %d\n", GetLastError());
        exit(0);
    }

    memset(results, 0, sizeof(results));

    ULONG numResults = rio.RIODequeueCompletion(completionQueue, results, RIO_MAX_RESULTS);
    if (0 == numResults || RIO_CORRUPT_CQ == numResults)
    {
        printf_s("RIODequeueCompletion Error: %d\n", GetLastError());
        exit(0);
    }

    const RIORESULT & res = results[0];
    if (0 != res.Status)
    {
        printf_s("RIOSend(Ex) Error: %d\n", res.Status);
        exit(0);
    }

    printf_s("RIOSend(Ex) OK\n");

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // active send code end ...
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    if (SOCKET_ERROR == ::closesocket(socket))
    {
        printf_s("closesocket Error: %d\n", GetLastError());
    }

    rio.RIOCloseCompletionQueue(completionQueue);

    rio.RIODeregisterBuffer(sendRioBufferId);
    rio.RIODeregisterBuffer(recvRioBufferId);
    rio.RIODeregisterBuffer(addrRioBufferId);

    return 0;
}
```

wish your help, Thanks!

yanrk

Answer (score 1):

From `RIOSendEx` documentation:

> sends network data on ... a **bound** ... UDP socket

Your example will work if you add those lines before calling `RIOSendEx`:

```
sockaddr_in addr{}; // zero-initialized
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

if (SOCKET_ERROR == ::bind(socket, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)))
{
    printf("bind failed\n");
    exit(0);
}

if (!rio.RIOSendEx(requestQueue ...
```

You can bind to some particular port (not recommended):

```
addr.sin_port = htons(5001);
```

Or leave it zero for OS to choose.

Aparently, RIOSendEx do not perform an implicit bind (unlike WSASendTo).

The reason for this might be that `bind` is a complicated process that might involve waiting and APC and all kinds of stuff, while whole idea of RIO is to pay upfront.

Answer (score 0):

connect + RIOSendEx doesn't make sense. Since you specified remote address with connect function you can't send data through that socket anywhere else. RIOSendEx is supposed to be used with datagrams.

Comment: the code is show that, "connect + RIOSend" work well, but "RIOSendEx" not. there is not "connect + RIOSendEx"

Answer (score 0):

You have not set the Destination IP-Address in the RioSendEx-Function:
Copy the content of your address-Buffer into the associated Buffer of addrRioBuffer.

e.g.:

```
memcpy_s(addrBuffer, ADDR_BUFFER_SIZE, address, sizeof(sockaddr_in));

if (!rio.RIOSendEx(requestQueue, &sendRioBuffer, 1, NULL, &addrRioBuffer, NULL, NULL, 0, &sendRioBuffer))
    {
        printf_s("RIOSendEx Error: %d\n", GetLastError());
        exit(0);
    }
// […]
```

I will post a working exampel in the next day´s.
http://www.thbweb.eu

Comment: Actually, the "address" is a pointer of "addrBuffer", so it would not work